# Upgrade Elasticsearch to the latest version

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, upgrade, elastic-stack

I want to upgrade my ES cluster(current version: 7.6.2) to the latest version (7.15.2 until now)
Is it ok to upgrade directly to the latest version or should I upgrade with 2 or 3 steps on different version?
For instance, for upgrading mongo db, it should be upgraded step by step to the next version...
I just want to know what is the policy or even best practice for upgrading ES ?!?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's totally fine to update between minor versions (7.x -> 7.y) as well as one major version up from latest minor version (6.8 -> 7.y), see [upgrading document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/setup-upgrade.html) for the details. Best of all, it can be a rolling upgrade so you can upgrade nodes in the cluster one by one without cluster downtime or data loss. Just make sure cluster health is green before moving on to the next node.